# Get Sum by group from one array and update the sum to another array for same group name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two array

```
levelOne = [
  {Code: "A", Count: 0, Date: 2017-04-01,....},
  {Code: "A", Count: 0, Date: 2017-05-01,....},
  {Code: "B", Count: 0, Date: 2017-04-01,....},
  {Code: "B", Count: 0, Date: 2017-05-01,....}
];    
levelTwo = [
  {Code: "A", Count: 10, Date: 2017-04-01,....},
  {Code: "A", Count: 12, Date: 2017-05-01,....},
  {Code: "B", Count: 50, Date: 2017-04-01,....},
  {Code: "B", Count: 18, Date: 2017-05-01,....},
  {Code: "A", Count: 20, Date: 2017-05-01,....},
  {Code: "B", Count: 60, Date: 2017-04-01,....},
  {Code: "B", Count: 77, Date: 2017-05-01,....}
];
```

I want to update the Count of levelOne array with the sum of Count in the levelTwo array for same Code and Date.

### What I done so far?

I put a $.each loop on levelOne and I was stuck.

```
    $.each( levelOne , function( index, value ){
                  //I'm stuck
        $.each( levelTwo , function( idx, val ){
             if(value.Code==val.Code && value.Date == val.Date){
                  //I'm stuck
             }
                  //I'm stuck                
        });
    });
```

Any Suggestion? Any better way to achieve it?

Comment: where do you get the data from? Often it is a good idea to retrieve the data in the desired format (from the database)

Comment: On a sidenote, why are you stuck? did just addnig the values not work?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pretty forward approach with a hash table and iterate first the target array and then the source array for counting.

With iterating `levelOne`, the hash table is filled with code and date values as key and the object itself as value.

Iterating `levelTwo` add the actual `Count` to the result array.

```js
var levelOne = [{ Code: "A", Count: 0, Date: '2017-04-01' }, { Code: "A", Count: 0, Date: '2017-05-01' }, { Code: "B", Count: 0, Date: '2017-04-01' }, { Code: "B", Count: 0, Date: '2017-05-01' }],
    levelTwo = [{ Code: "A", Count: 10, Date: '2017-04-01' }, { Code: "A", Count: 12, Date: '2017-05-01' }, { Code: "B", Count: 50, Date: '2017-04-01' }, { Code: "B", Count: 18, Date: '2017-05-01' }, { Code: "A", Count: 20, Date: '2017-05-01' }, { Code: "B", Count: 60, Date: '2017-04-01' }, { Code: "B", Count: 77, Date: '2017-05-01' }],
    getKey = function (o) { return ['Code', 'Date'].map(function (k) { return o[k]; }).join('|'); },
    hash = Object.create(null);

levelOne.forEach(function (o) { hash[getKey(o)] = o; });
levelTwo.forEach(function (o) { hash[getKey(o)].Count += o.Count; });
   
console.log(levelOne);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var levelOne = [{ Code: "A", Count: 0, Date: '2017-04-01' }, { Code: "A", Count: 0, Date: '2017-05-01' }, { Code: "B", Count: 0, Date: '2017-04-01' }, { Code: "B", Count: 0, Date: '2017-05-01' }],
    levelTwo = [{ Code: "A", Count: 10, Date: '2017-04-01' }, { Code: "A", Count: 12, Date: '2017-05-01' }, { Code: "B", Count: 50, Date: '2017-04-01' }, { Code: "B", Count: 18, Date: '2017-05-01' }, { Code: "A", Count: 20, Date: '2017-05-01' }, { Code: "B", Count: 60, Date: '2017-04-01' }, { Code: "B", Count: 77, Date: '2017-05-01' }],
    hash = new Map,
    getKey = o => ['Code', 'Date'].map(k => o[k]).join('|');

levelOne.forEach(o => hash.set(getKey(o), o));
levelTwo.forEach(o => hash.get(getKey(o)).Count += o.Count);
   
console.log(levelOne);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
levelOne = [
  {Code: "A", Count: 0, Date: '2017-04-01'},
  {Code: "A", Count: 0, Date: '2017-05-01'},
  {Code: "B", Count: 0, Date: '2017-04-01'},
  {Code: "B", Count: 0, Date: '2017-05-01'}
];    
levelTwo = [
  {Code: "A", Count: 10, Date: '2017-04-01'},
  {Code: "A", Count: 12, Date: '2017-05-01'},
  {Code: "B", Count: 50, Date: '2017-04-01'},
  {Code: "B", Count: 18, Date: '2017-05-01'},
  {Code: "A", Count: 20, Date: '2017-05-01'},
  {Code: "B", Count: 60, Date: '2017-04-01'},
  {Code: "B", Count: 77, Date: '2017-05-01'}
];

$.each( levelOne , function( index, value ){
    $.each( levelTwo , function( idx, val ){
         if(value.Code==val.Code && value.Date == val.Date){

               //just increment the value of your levelOne array here.
               value.Count += val.Count;
               //~or~
               //levelOne[index].Count += val.count;

         } 
    });
});

//example - just prints the results to a div
$.each( levelOne , function( index, value ){
    $("#results").append(value.Code + " - " + value.Count + " - " + value.Date + "<br />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a helper array to store the added counts:

```
var helper = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < levelTwo.length; i++) {

    var entry = levelTwo[i];
    helper[entry.Code][entry.Date] += entry.Count;

}
```

Afterwards you loop again in a double loop through the helper array to place the value into levelOne

**Edit:**

Compete example:

```
var levelOne = new Array(
  {Code: "A", Count: 0, Date: '2017-04-01'},
  {Code: "A", Count: 0, Date: '2017-05-01'},
  {Code: "B", Count: 0, Date: '2017-04-01'},
  {Code: "B", Count: 0, Date: '2017-05-01'}
);    
var levelTwo = new Array(
  {Code: "A", Count: 10, Date: '2017-04-01'},
  {Code: "A", Count: 12, Date: '2017-05-01'},
  {Code: "B", Count: 50, Date: '2017-04-01'},
  {Code: "B", Count: 18, Date: '2017-05-01'},
  {Code: "A", Count: 20, Date: '2017-05-01'},
  {Code: "B", Count: 60, Date: '2017-04-01'},
  {Code: "B", Count: 77, Date: '2017-05-01'}
);


var helper = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < levelTwo.length; i++) {

    if(typeof helper[levelTwo[i].Code] == 'undefined') {
        console.log('reset ' + levelTwo[i].Code);
        helper[levelTwo[i].Code] = new Array();
    }
    if(typeof helper[levelTwo[i].Code][levelTwo[i].Date] == 'undefined') {
        helper[levelTwo[i].Code][levelTwo[i].Date] = 0;
    }
    helper[levelTwo[i].Code][levelTwo[i].Date] += levelTwo[i].Count;
}


for(var j=0; j<levelOne.length;j++) {
    if(helper[levelOne[j].Code][levelOne[j].Date]) {
        levelOne[j].Count = helper[levelOne[j].Code][levelOne[j].Date];
    }
    else {
        levelOne[j].Count = 0;
    }
}
```

**Note:**
it should not be possible the levelTwo array contains a reference to non-exsisting elements in leverOne

Comment: i think that just adds an unnecesary loop. why not change the values in levelOne directly?

Comment: Could be done, but then you need to set the value to 0 before. And you will have to lookup the correct array element each time

Answer (score 0):

Try This code-

```
for(i = 0; i < levelOne.length; i++){
    for(var  j = 0; j < levelTwo.length; j++) {
        if(levelOne[i]['Code'] == levelTwo[j]['Code'] && levelOne[i]['Date'] == levelTwo[j]['Date']){
            levelOne[i]['Count'] += levelTwo[j]['Count'];
        }
    }
}
console.log(levelOne);
```